# Polynomial vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

$R^3[x]$ is the vector space of the polynomial functions of degree $<= 3$.
$$
W = \left\{p(x) \in R^3[x] : p(0) = p'(0) = 0 \right\} 
$$

What does that condition
$$
p(0) = p'(0) = 0
$$
really mean?

Can someone please give me an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the polynomial and its first derivative are  zero at $x=0$. An example would be:

$$f(x)=x^2.$$

Here is another point:

Let $p(x)=a_3 x^3+a_2 x^2+a_1 x+a_0$. Notice that $a_0=0$ by the condition that $p(0)=0$. This is because if you plug $x=0$ into $p(x)$, you get $$a_3 \cdot 0^3+a_2 \cdot  0^2+a_1 \cdot 0+a_0=a_0.$$

Take $p^{\prime}(x)=3a_3x^2+2a_2x^2+a_1$. Notice that $a_1$ must also be zero by the condition that $p^{\prime}(0)=0$.

So, $p(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2$ for all $p(x) \in W$.

Comment: So because of that we'll have an example of a basis: $W_b = \left\{ x^2,x^3 \right\} $

Comment: yes, that's exactly right. You should verify for yourself that $W_b$ is a linear subspace.

Comment: That's really so abstract... think of polynomials as subspaces and vector spaces... But it's nice to generalize things. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @BrunoReis This isn't directly related to your question, but notice that the derivative operator $D$ is a linear map on $R^3[x]$.  That is, $D$ sends each polynomial to its derivative, which is also a polynomial of degree at most 3.  You might have fun finding the $4\times 4$ matrix that represents $D$.

Comment: Yeah, derivatives are linear transformations... I've read something about it in last week. That's really cool!

Comment: The first line is wrong. One says a function is "identically zero" if it is zero for every argument. This is the opposite. It is zero for only one argument.

Comment: Thanks Matt, thats correct.

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ is a polynomial in this vector space, then
\begin{equation}
p(x) = a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0
\end{equation}
for some coefficients $a_0,\ldots,a_3$.  Then $p(0)=a_0$ and $p'(0)=a_1$, so your requirement means that in fact $p(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2$.

Comment: Why does $p(0) = a_0$?

Comment: If we substitute $x=0$, the first three terms vanish, since they all contain an $x$.  Showing that $p'(0)=a_1$ is similar.

Comment: OOOOOH, so $p(0)$ is a function where you plug-in $x = 0$ and, because of that you'll have left just the first term of a basis for the space of all polynomials of degree $<=3$. Right?

Comment: Right.  So $W$ is the two-dimensional subspace spanned by the basis elements $x^3$ and $x^2$.

Comment: I assume that $p(0)$ is not a function. It is the evaluation of $p(x)$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @AndresMejia Correct.  I believe Bruno meant that $p(x)$ is a function; certainly $p(0)$ is just a number.

Comment: Yeah @AustinC , i meant that $p(x)$ is a function... I'll edit it. Thanks for the answer. Both of you answered the same thing, that's why I'm not going to choose the best or better answer. Thank you for your time <3